# How do i get the total count of data objects in this API response

Tags: javascript, json, api

Im trying to write a code that retrieves data from a db and verifies if its matches the data that is synced in an online tool
For that i need to know the number of ROWS created in the db table for comparison. A table is created for each entry and it goes something like this:

```
type: list
data: [ 
       {count 1},
       {count 2},
       {count 3}
       ]
```

now i need to get the number of "counts" in this object (which is 3 in this example). Some API's have a total_count tag which is helpul in getting me my info. but others dont. Anyway i can get that number?

Answer (score 1):

If your Response is allways in an Array use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```
let apiRes = {data: [1,2,3]};
console.log(apiRes.data.length);
```